# data.table: temporarily rename single column while keeping all others

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the table below:

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1, y = 10, z = 100, w = 1000)
```

I want to rename the column `z` to `y`, while keeping one or more columns in the table. The columns and renaming would be specified by variables. For example:

```
keep <- c("x", "w")
old <- "z"
new <- "y"
# Manually:
DT[, .(x, w, y = z)]
```

In addition to that, I want the original `y` column to still exist. That is, I want the renaming to be temporary, and to be able to go back to the original table.

Solutions I tried:

1. Partially manual with `..`. But returns something I did not expect and do not understand why that was returned.

```
DT[, .(..keep, y = z)]
>    ..keep   y
> 1:      x 100
> 2:      w 100
```

2. Selecting everything but the column that would be replaced, then renaming with `setnames`:

```
keep <- setdiff(colnames(DT), "y")
newDT <- DT[, ..keep]
data.table::setnames(new_DT, old, new)
print(newDT)
>   x   y    w
> 1: 1 100 1000
```

The second option works as expected, but it does not copy values by reference.

3. Using `dplyr::select` and `dplyr::rename`.

```
newDT <- dplyr::rename(dplyr::select(DT, -y), y = z)
```

Works as expected, but copies are not by reference, and I need `dplyr` instead of just using `data.table`.

**Question:** Is there a way of temporarily renaming one column while keeping other columns around, without copying data (done by reference)? That is, is there a way to recreate a table by reference for most columns, except change one of them.

Thanks for helping! Please let me know is something is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a one-liner that accomplishes the answer by reference, but I was able to use `setnames` to obtain a solution that does not copy the data.

Consider the original data:

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1, y = 10, z = 100, w = 1000)
.Internal(inspect(DT))
> @1b588e10 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,REF(7),ATT] (len=4, tl=1028)
  @1510aea0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @1510b1b0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 10
  @1510b4f8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 100
  @151079a0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1000
```

To rename `z` into `y` without losing `y` and not copying any data, we need to:

1. Rename the original `y` into something else with `setnames` (this is done by reference):

```
setnames(DT, "y", "y_original")
.Internal(inspect(DT))
> @1b588e10 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,REF(17),ATT] (len=4, tl=1028)
  @1510aea0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @1510b1b0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 10
  @1510b4f8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 100
  @151079a0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1000
```

2. Rename `z` into `y` with `setnames`:

```
setnames(DT, "z", "y")
.Internal(inspect(DT))
> @1b588e10 19 VECSXP g0c7 [OBJ,REF(27),ATT] (len=4, tl=1028)
  @1510aea0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1
  @1510b1b0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 10
  @1510b4f8 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 100
  @151079a0 14 REALSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 1000
```

Then, the resulting table `DT` still has all columns in `keep`, the column `z` was renamed to `y`, the original column `y` is still available (but now `y_original`), and no data was copied in the process.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `mget` to return the values of 'keep' in a `list` and then concatenate (`c`) with the list renamed (`.(y = z)`)

```
 DT[,  c(mget(keep), .(y = z))]
```

-output

```
      x     w     y
   <num> <num> <num>
1:     1  1000   100
```

Comment: That is concise, but the values of the `keep` columns actually get copied instead of being copied by reference. Check the outputs of `.Internal(inspect(DT))` and `.Internal(inspect(DT[,  c(mget(keep), .(y = z))]))`.

Comment: What about `DT[, ..keep][, y := DT[['z']]][]`

Comment: I just realized that even the first step of `DT[, ..keep]` will copy data. Even if you are keeping the same columns! For example, `keep <- c("x", "y", "z", "w")`, then `DT[, ..keep]` will already have copied the data. Use `.Internal(inspect(...))` to confirm.

Comment: Wouldn't the one you mentioned also should change the original data if it is by reference i.e. `setnames(DT, 'z', 'y')`

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it. I appreciate your comments.